# Longtable line thickness

Tags: longtable

I have a problem with the longtable line thickness.
The header row left vertical line thickness is wrong.
Unfortunately, I am not able to upload the screenshot due to the Imgur server error ("Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server").

Here is the code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\def\arraystretch{2}
\begin{longtable}{V{3}l|l|l|lV{3}}
\caption{My caption.} \label{tab:myLbl} \\
\hlineB{3}
\(n\) & \(k\)  & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Comments} \\ \hlineB{3}
\multirow{4}{*}{1} & \multirow{4}{*}{1000} & \multirow{2}{*}{abc}   & \( x^{2} + y^{2}  \)  \\ \cline{4-4}
                   &                         &                      & \( x^{2} + y^{2} \)   \\ \cline{3-4}
                   &                         & \multirow{2}{*}{def} & \( x^{2} + y^{2} \)   \\ \cline{4-4}
                   &                         &                      & \( x^{2} + y^{2} \)   \\ \hlineB{3}
\multirow{4}{*}{2} & \multirow{4}{*}{2000} & \multirow{2}{*}{abc}   & \( x^{2} + y^{2} \)   \\ \cline{4-4}
                   &                         &                      & \( x^{2} + y^{2} \)   \\ \cline{3-4}
                   &                         & \multirow{2}{*}{def} & \( x^{2} + y^{2} \)   \\ \cline{4-4}
                   &                         &                      & \( x^{2} + y^{2} \)   \\ \hlineB{3}             
\end{longtable}
\end{table}
```

I am using `\usepackage{boldline}` package

Thanks.

Comment: You surely don’t want `table` around `longtable`

Comment: `\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Comments} ` should be `\multicolumn{2}{l|}{Comments} ` rules are only on the right edge, apart from the first column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot to David Carlisle for the idea!

```
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Comments}
```

replaced by

```
\multicolumn{2}{lV{3}}{Comments}
```

It solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You want `\multicolumn{2}{lV{3}}` instead of `\multicolumn{2}{|l|}` which is wrong under two respects: it adds an unwanted rule (at the left) and doesn't reflect `V{3}` in the rule at the right.

There are other aspects to fix. If you want a `table` environment, you surely don't want `longtable`, whose purpose is allow the table to be split across pages.

You also don't want `[H]`, whose only effect is to make typesetting difficult and to, likely, cause bad page breaks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\caption{My caption.} \label{tab:myLbl}

\begin{tabular}{V{3}l|l|l|lV{3}}
\hlineB{3}
\(n\) & \(k\)  & \multicolumn{2}{lV{3}}{Comments} \\ \hlineB{3}
\multirow{4}{*}{1} & \multirow{4}{*}{1000} & \multirow{2}{*}{abc} & \( x^{2} + y^{2} \) \\
\cline{4-4}
                   &                       &                      & \( x^{2} + y^{2} \) \\
\cline{3-4}
                   &                       & \multirow{2}{*}{def} & \( x^{2} + y^{2} \) \\
\cline{4-4}
                   &                       &                      & \( x^{2} + y^{2} \) \\
\hlineB{3}
\multirow{4}{*}{2} & \multirow{4}{*}{2000} & \multirow{2}{*}{abc} & \( x^{2} + y^{2} \) \\
\cline{4-4}
                   &                       &                      & \( x^{2} + y^{2} \) \\
\cline{3-4}
                   &                       & \multirow{2}{*}{def} & \( x^{2} + y^{2} \) \\
\cline{4-4}
                   &                       &                      & \( x^{2} + y^{2} \) \\
\hlineB{3}
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also suggest a different rendering.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{My caption.} \label{tab:myLbl-new}

\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\toprule
\(n\) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\(k\)}  & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Comments} \\
\midrule
1 & 1000 & abc & \( x^{2} + y^{2} \) \\
  &      &     & \( x^{2} + y^{2} \) \\
  &      & def & \( x^{2} + y^{2} \) \\
  &      &     & \( x^{2} + y^{2} \) \\
\addlinespace
2 & 2000 & abc & \( x^{2} + y^{2} \) \\
  &      &     & \( x^{2} + y^{2} \) \\
  &      & def & \( x^{2} + y^{2} \) \\
  &      &     & \( x^{2} + y^{2} \) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks egreg, I actually want 'longtable', in order to split the table over two pages.
I used 'longtblr' and I was quite happy. 
But now Overleaf fails to compile my project unless I delete all 'longtblr' tables. So, I am working on a workaround with  'longtable'.

Comment: @ab3001 Then, as I said, you don't want `table` around it.

Comment: Yes. I removed it. Thanks.